# Help Tkinter abrindo uma aplicação Python

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

Fiz um menu separado para achar minhas aplicações e ela abre normalmente, mas se fechar não consigo abrir de novo, só fechando a aplicação do menu.

```
from tkinter import *

def Cadcordenadores():
      from Cadcordenador import Application

def Cadalunos():
      from Cadalunos import Application

root = Tk()
root.title('App')
root.geometry('800x600')
menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Cordenadores", command = Cadcordenadores)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label = "Alunos", command = Cadalunos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Módulos são executados quando são importados, somente uma vez. Veja o que acontece, por exemplo, nessa linha:

```
import Cadcordenador
```

Esse comando compila e executa o conteúdo integral do módulo `Cadcordenador`. O módulo inteiro será executado - Funções e classes serão definidas e qualquer código que estiver no corpo do módulo vai passar pela execução.

Em seguida todas as variáveis criadas pelo módulo são armazenadas automaticamente pelo python em um objeto do tipo `module`  que fica em `sys.modules['Cadcordenador']` - isso é tipo um *"cache"*.

Se no futuro, alguma outra parte do código executar novamente o comando:

```
import Cadcordenador
```

Dessa vez como `sys.modules` já tem a chave `Cadcordenador`, o módulo não é executado novamente. Ao invés disso é retornado o objeto que já tinha sido gerado na primeira execução.

Por isso, a forma correta de rodar um mesmo código duas vezes é **colocá-lo em uma função**. Isso deve ser feito dentro do seu módulo `Cadcordenador`. Por exemplo, se o seu módulo estiver assim:

```
# Cadcordenador.py

class Application:
    ....

app = Application()
root.mainloop()
```

Nesse exemplo o `mainloop()` está no corpo principal do módulo e só vai rodar uma vez quando ele for importado. Você deve alterar e colocar o código que você quer que repita dentro de uma função:

```
class Application:
    ....

def run():
    app = Application()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Como você pode ver, a parte que inicia a aplicação agora está dentro da função `run()`;

O `if __name__ == '__main__'` serve para proteger a execução automática do código quando o mesmo for importado. Em outras palavras, ele faz com que a função `run()` seja chamada automaticamente somente quando esse módulo `Cadcordenador` esteja sendo executado diretamente, e não importado. Quando ele for importado, a variável `__name__` será `'Cadcordenador'` e não `'__main__'`.

Com isso, ao usar no seu outro módulo

```
 import Cadcordenador
```

Nada vai acontecer, porque a função `run()` ainda não rodou, porém, já está definida. Você pode rodá-la quantas vezes quiser:

```
 Cadcordenador.run()
```

Comment: Boa tarde, fiz conforme explicado e o modulo Cadalunos.py roda, mas quando tento chamar no outro modulo a função ela da a mensagem: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\t010038655\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Users\t010038655\Documents\teste\App.py", line 13, in Cadalunos
    Cadalunos.run()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: Parece que tem uma função com o mesmo nome do módulo sendo definida no seu código, @WellingtonRamos